# Admob ads not showing for app downloaded from Amazon Appstore

Tags: android, google-play, admob, ads, amazon-appstore

My app when downloaded from Google Play is showing Admob ads. However the same app when downloaded from the Amazon Appstore does not show any. I've searched and could not find a solution to this problem. Has someone come across this issue and found a solution?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Something happens to the APK file when you upload it to the Amzon Appstore that renders Google AdMob practically useless. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Come here looking for a solution!

Answer (score 0):

It could take some time for the ADS to be showed

https://support.google.com/admob/thread/113218450/why-are-my-ads-not-showing-in-app-on-amazon-store?hl=en